# Isomorphism between subgroups of $S_p$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Consider the group $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$. Can it be isomorpic to a subgroup of a symmetric group $S_n$ for some prime $n\leq p$.
Here $p$ is prime.

It is enough if it's possible to show that the existence of a isomorphism between $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ and $S_p$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: Consider the orders of elements in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}\text{ \ } p\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: The minimal faithful permutation degrees for $GL_2(p)$ for small $p$ are `[ [ 2, 3 ], [ 3, 8 ], [ 5, 24 ], [ 7, 19 ], [ 11, 29 ], [ 13, 59 ],
  [ 17, 288 ], [ 19, 49 ], [ 23, 59 ], [ 29, 127 ] ]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First it is clear that there is no isomorphism between $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ and a subgroup of $S_2$ because $\text{ord}(S_2)=2<\text{ord}(GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}))$.

Now take $p>2$ be a prime and define $P,Q\in GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z})$ by
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}p-1&0\\0&p-1\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Inductively we can show that, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$Q^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore $\text{ord}(Q)=p$ and $\text{ord}(P)=2$. It's clear that $PQ=QP$. Since $P,Q$ commutes, we have that $\text{ord}(PQ)=\text{lcm}(\text{ord}(P),\text{ord}(Q))=\text{lcm}(2,p)=2p$. (Since $p$ is prime and $p\neq 2$. )

Now suppose there is a isomorphism $\varphi:GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z})\to S_p$. Then $\text{ord}(\varphi(AB))=2p$.
But, only elements in $S_p$ have orders divisible by $p$ are $p$ cycles which has order $p$.

Hence, there is no isomorphism between subgroups of $S_p$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I got it. A great answer.

Comment: "But, for all $n$, all elements of $S_n$ has orders less than or equal to $n$". But $S_5$ has elements of order $6$, $S_7$ has elements of order $12$ etc etc.

Comment: Sorry, I also had make a simple mistake in my question. Now it is okay

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thankyou, I corrected the mistake.

Comment: I think  i can understand this, that there is no isomorphisms between subgroups of $S_p$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: For primes less than $p$, this method may not be working.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{GL}_2(p)$ has a centre of order $p-1$ (the scalar matrices), and a subgroup of order $p$ (the upper unitriangular matrices). Thus an element of order $p$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(p)$ commutes with an element of order $p-1>1$ (if $p\neq 2$). But in $S_p$, the $p$-cycle does not commute with any element of order strictly between $1$ and $p$. Thus $\mathrm{GL}_2(p)$, and indeed $\mathrm{SL}_2(p)$ for $p>2$, cannot be a subgroup of $S_p$ (or $S_{p+1}$).

We need something like this because the *projective* group $\mathrm{PSL}_2(5)$ is isomorphic to $A_5$, hence a subgroup of $S_5$, and $\mathrm{PSL}_2(7)$ is a subgroup of $S_7$.